# How to detect which element is visible/on-top directly or through the cavities of another element at a given point?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Suppose I have a div (background set to blue), and inside it, there is a `<h1>` containing some text in white.

Using the javascript function `elementFromPoint()`, I can find which element is currently at a given coordinate(x,y), but this function only checks the bounds, and not actual visibility. e.g. if `<h1>` contains the text `"HELLO"`, then from inside the "O", the background (blue) div is actually visible, but the `elementFromPoint()` function still detects the `<h1>` tag there, because it only checks the bounding-box of the `<h1>`.

Is there any javascript function/library using which I can detect the actually visible object at a point? (See the picture below for the problem I'm facing)

[image: See this picture below, I want a function which can detect the DIV correctly]

Comment: So, do you want to detect the `<div>` using `elementFromPoint()`?

Comment: yes, please see the picture above... I want to detect the DIV correctly through the "O" using some function....

Answer (score 0):

Use [visible selector](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/):

```
$(selector).is(':visible');
```

---

You have html like this:

```
<div><h1></h1></div>
```

So, applying visibility hidden to div it still shows the h1 tag. [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/L4VZc/)

And if you apply display none to div then h1 tag is hidden. [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/L4VZc/1/)

---

So, you might be having visibility property instead of display. Thus change it with `display: none;`

Comment: this won't work, because both div and h1 are visible. Actually, the div is visible through the inner cavities of the text contained in h1. I want to detect that : which is visible, the h1 at the point, or the background div through the h1 ?

Comment: no, you don't understand... I do not want to hide/display anything... Please see the picture in the question. I want to detect which element is being shown at some coordinate(x,y), whether directly or through some hole of any other element on top of it.