# Web Worker Javascript cannot find functions in other javascript files

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an HTML file like this:

```
<html>

    <head>

        <title>World Aviation</title>

        <script language="javascript" src="./jquery-min.js"> </script>
        <script language="javascript" src="./jsDraw2D.js"> </script>
        <script language="javascript" src="./script.js"> </script>
    </head>
<body>

         <input onClick="startAnimBackground();" type="button" value="Start"/>

         <script language="javascript">

                initAirports();

                initRoutes();

            var w;

            function startAnimBackground()
            {
                if(typeof(Worker) !== "undefined")
                {
                    if(typeof(w) == "undefined")
                    {
                        w = new Worker("start_script.js");
                    }
                } else {
                    startAnimation();
                }
            }
         </script>

</body> 

</html>
```

the file "start_script.js" contains only 1 line which calls the startAnimation() function. This function is located in "script.js"

My problem is: my browser supports web-workers, so it creates a web-worker and loads the file "start_script.js", but it fails to call the function "startAnimation()" indicating that it cannot find the function. But this function is located in script.js which is included in the head section. So, the only conclusion I can draw is that web-worker JS files have a different scope and thus is not able to include the 3 javascript files specified in the head section. So what should I do to make this work? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Web workers don't share functions, variables, or scripts with the main script.

To load dependencies, call `importScripts()` in your worker.

To allow your web worker to interact with or affect the main script or the DOM, you have to use message passing and have the main script listen for, interpret, and act on the messages.

See:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Performance/Using_web_workers

Comment: I imported all the 3 scripts using importScripts() like you said, but when I imported JQuery (one of the 3 scripts), it throws an error "window is not defined". I guess this was natural because it has no access to the window object, as a web-worker. So, I'm back to square-one. What should I do now? I need JQuery in my script, and I cannot possibly use message-passing with JQuery...

Comment: If you are just trying to make an animation in the background, try to make it `setTimeout()` based and don't use a web worker.

Comment: My animation is actually continuous (so I cannot use setTimeout): multiple aircrafts moving about from one airport to another. So, I had to use the animate() JQuery function on each aircraft. But, whenever the number of aircrafts >= 200, my browser crashes. That's the problem. I thought that I could improve the performance using web-workers...

Comment: Maybe you ran out of memory?

Comment: Actually it does not literally crash/terminate, rather it stops responding after a few seconds, and Chrome displays a message asking it to kill the page. Also when I use 100-150, the animation (movement of the aircrafts) is jittery and the page is not-responsive (e.g. scrolling is intermittently responsive).

Comment: You have too many instances of animate. Can you do it with less? Would grouping flights into squadrons help?

Comment: no, its not military aircraft. They are commercial airliners, so I can't group them, because each aircraft's source and destination are different airports.
and Thanks @Paul for the support, and I would really really appreciate if you could also help me out with another question I haven't had any answer to, since the last 2 days: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22553888

Thanks & Regards

Comment: That question, I don't know.  And, the answer is device-dependent I think, which doesn't bode well for getting an answer.

Comment: I know this is pretty old but this is the only question that matches my issues exactly. But instead of crashing my webpage or browser, it instead crashed my computer when trying it his way. I used webworkers to help with it but I needed to use an external file. It wasn't jquery but came up with the same error as "window is not defined." Sometimes when placing entire links, is says "Uncaught null".

Comment: @JonathanJ.Pecany I haven't kept up with the progress in web workers.  I think you should ask a new question.

Comment: @Paul Okay then, I will.